# getting this erorr SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm very new to python and programming over all and I'm getting this error

```
>>> python C:\Users\Spravce\Desktop\hello1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python C:\Users\Spravce\Desktop\hello1.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Python scripts with python command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305764/how-to-execute-python-scripts-with-python-command)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run python inside the Python Interactive Shell

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode

exit from it using command `quit()` and run your command in the system shell instead :)